# Apache serving static files within VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, httpd, static-content

I have the following VirtualHost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName myservername.website

        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently there are a series of static files living in /var/www/static that the `ProxyPass` app is serving. I would rather that Apache served this.

I have no idea how to just say - "When a request to /static is received then serve it from /var/www/static on the filesystem". How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myservername.website
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/static/
    RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:5000/ [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Alias /static "/var/www/static"
<Directory "/var/www/static">
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory
```

Comment: Also make sure that the user apache is running under has permission to read the files.

Comment: Adding this to the VirtualHost did not work. Am I doing this wrong? Please note there are other VirtualHosts on the server and this should only affect one of them.