# Serving Static Content with Apache2

Tags: apache2, static-content

I am really new to apache2 and have previously worked with Nginx.  I am trying to use alias in apache2 to serve static content.  Starting off with a simple example.

I tried [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/67298) out and it didn't work either.  Advice?

**000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 13.67.35.134
    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/static/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried it with quotes too based on this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/735908/apache-serving-static-files-within-virtualhost):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName 13.67.35.134
    Alias /static "/home/ubuntu/static"
    <Directory "/home/ubuntu/static">
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I have logo.png located at

```
/home/ubuntu/static/logo.png
```

**alias_module is enabled:**

```
$ apache2ctl -M | grep alias
 alias_module (shared)
```

When I type in 13.67.35.134/static/logo.png, I get a **404**, this is the
access.log

```
[26/Jan/2018:02:31:02 +0000] "GET /static/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 423 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

**Solution**

Thanks @AndrewSchulman for pointing out that the Proxy Pass in my 000-default.conf file threw off the ability to access my static content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have another web server running on localhost:5000 (and I don't know why you'd do that, except for testing I guess), you should remove the `ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/` directive.

Answer (score 1):

I see this is resolved but for anyone else coming across this and needing to keep the ProxyPass config, you can specify to ignore the static URL (at some point between the Alias and ProxyPass config lines, add `ProxyPass /static !`). (Related q&a regarding static files & ProxyPass [here](https://serverfault.com/a/379671/805867))